# Who designed this Ubuntu Wallpaper?

Tags: desktop-background

I want to know who designed this marvelous wallpaper for Ubuntu I believe it was version 11.10. It is amazing and I want to see more of the artist's work.
[image]

Comment: Wow! surprised to see this hasn't been taken down. I'll post my finding as an answer then.

Answer (score 2):

The artist is apparently called **Sayantan Chaudhuri**. You may visit their [*flickr* profile](https://www.flickr.com/photos/55253462@N03/).